# .htaccess Запрет сжатия страницы (gzip)

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как запретить .htaccess сжимать страницы?
У меня выходит так
`.htaccess (сервер)->.htaccess (в папке с проектом)`

Как мне через `.htaccess (в папке с проектом)` запретить работу `gzip` на `.htaccess (сервер)`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить строку в .htaccess в папке с проектом

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI /$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

Comment: Не помогло, думаю это особенности хостинга и его прокси, а не особенности апача на хостинге. А так спс, если на другом хостинге появится такое использую ваш метод.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не получится переопрепределить глобальные настройки всего сервера с помощью локального файла конфигурации. 
Если хотите изменить настройки сервера, редактируйте `httpd.conf`.
Например можно закоментировать загрузку модуля сжатия.

```
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

В Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo a2dismod deflate
```

И не забудьте перезапустить сам Apache.

Comment: А не подскажите где находится файл httpd.conf, осина linux, без sudo, доступ по sftp

Comment: Это зависит от семейства Linux. Бывает в /etc/apache или /etc/httpd, но может быть и просто внутри /etc или /opt/local/etc. Вариантов много.